# Insert XML from Nokogiri xml builder block into another using a method call

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to build xml for a library I'm making. What I'm trying to do is this:

```
def block1
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.SomeStuff {
      xml.ThingsUnderStuff
      (block2 needs to go here)
    }
  end
end

def block2
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.AddedToStuff {}
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what to do, I haven't been able to find any thing in the documentation that I could use for this unless I overlooked it.  Thanks for anyone's help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
def block1
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.SomeStuff {
      xml.ThingsUnderStuff
      block2(xml)
    }
  end
end

def block2(xml)
    xml.AddedToStuff
end

puts block1.doc
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <SomeStuff>
#=>   <ThingsUnderStuff/>
#=>   <AddedToStuff/>
#=> </SomeStuff>
```